# Terminology - Does a nested loop have to be in another loop?

Tags: nested, terminology

Typically, when someone refers to a nested loop, I think of a loop inside a loop. Same for a nested if statement - an if inside an if.

But does it have to refer to that? I mean, would you consider a loop inside an if statement a nested loop? Or an if inside a loop a nested if?

Basically, to be a nested *x*, does the thing that it is nested inside of have to be another *x*?

**Note**: Hopefully obvious, but I'm not asking if it's possible to do these things. Of course it's possible. I'm asking about terminology - "would it make sense to refer to these things this way", not "is it possible to do this thing I'm describing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I would say that for a loop to be called nested that it is inside of another loop. This distinction may seem trivial in everyday discussion, but when it comes to analyzing the Big-O runtime of code it makes a huge difference for a "nested" loop to actually be inside of another loop and not an if block.

Answer (score 1):

You would refer to loops nested in if statements or vice versa as *nested code blocks* or *nested statements*.

Nested loops must be nested in other loops and nested if statements must be nested in other if statements.